# Team foundation WorkItemResultGrid data not being displayed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, vs-extensibility

I am working on adding a workitem tracking WorkItemResultGrid into a VS 2015 tool window.  The ResultOptions and WorkItemCollection seem to be set up correctly (inspection in debugger).  The grid data context appears to be bound correctly to the workitem collection. The tool window is displayed within VS and the outline of the header row and the one populated data row are visible but neither show any text.

Am I missing a setup step?

XAML:

```
<DataGrid>
    <wtc:WorkItemResultGrid x:Name="TfsWorkItemResultGrid">

    </wtc:WorkItemResultGrid>
</DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
public partial class ToolWindowLayout : UserControl
{
    public ToolWindowLayout()
    {
        DisplayFieldCollection theDisplayFields = new DisplayFieldCollection();
        theDisplayFields.Add(new DisplayField("Id", 50));
        theDisplayFields.Add(new DisplayField("Title", 200));
        TfsWorkItemResultGrid.ResultOptions = new ResultOptions(theDisplayFields, new SortFieldCollection());

        // plug in some test data for now
        string workItemId = "169352";
        string tfsWorkStoreQuery = "SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title] FROM WorkItems ";
        tfsWorkStoreQuery += "WHERE [System.TeamProject] = \"EITS\" AND [System.Id] = " + workItemId;
        WorkItemCollection workItemCollection = theWorkItemStore.theStore.Query(tfsWorkStoreQuery);
        TfsWorkItemResultGrid.WorkItemCollection = workItemCollection;
    }
}
```

I was unsure whether to use just "Id" or "System.Id" in the DisplayField.  I have tried both with no different result.  When I look inside the TfsWorkItemResultGrid.WorkItemCollection in the debugger, the data member name is just "Id".

Any suggestion about what to try next would be very much appreciated.